# C# custom control: Use internal content as Text field

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom control, and I want to get all the stuff within the tags and use it as a string Text field on my control:

i.e.

```
<custom:control ID="C" runat="server">This text should go into the text property</custom:control>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I've tried the following attributes on my text field (copied from the Literal control) but it doesn't seem to work!

```
    [DefaultValue(""), Bindable(true), Localizable(true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

On the control class:

```
[ParseChildren(true, "TextPropertyNameHere")]
[PersistChildren(false)]
```

On the control's property:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
```

Or something like that.